# Web API/MVC Data Binding - Disambiguate "null" from "not provided"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Let's say the server has a simple model with a nullable property like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now say Client A POSTs an old version of the `Foo` model, back when `Foo` did not have the `Value` property.

```
{ "id": 123 }
```

and Client B POSTs the complete `Foo` because its version does know what `Value` is.

```
{ "id": 123, "value": null }
```

Because the MVC model binder will see the absence of the `value` key and assign `null` to `Foo.Value`, the scenario is effectively ambiguous to someone consuming this data. Consider if I was sending this data up to the server to update a record. I could potentially `null` out values simply because the calling client didn't know anything about the `Value` property, as opposed to `Value` being explicitly set to `null`.

Effectively this is a model versioning issue. However, looking at the raw JSON from Client A it's obvious that it didn't know about `Value`, which instructs me to retain the existing value of the `Value` property. When received from Client B, it instructs me to update the value to `null` because it is explicitly provided.

Is there any way to accomplish this with Web API/MVC, or will I end up having to do something like explicitly define and pass in a model version that will allow the server to know which "dialect" of `Foo` that a client is talking?

Comment: no need to use quotation for parameters. use lie {id:123,value:null}

Comment: "instructs me to retain the existing value of the Value property" 
This means you have some predefined value for `value` ,just pass it to your model if not changed you can assume user does not know else update it

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe sorry, I probably wasn't clear in my original question. The primary issue is the Client A has an old understanding of what `Foo` is, in that it doesn't know that `Foo` has a `Value` property.

Comment: If you do end up versioning, I would not version the model by requiring clients to send an additional parameter in the data. Instead, you should version the route and have the data sent to a different controller and/or action method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making `value` an `object' rather than`null able decimal`. This would solve your problem:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ValueObject Value { get; set; }
}

public class ValueObject
{
     public decimal? Value { get; set;}
}
```

This way when for `client A` value the object will be `null`
where as for `client B` value of the property inside `ValueObject` will be `null`.

Comment: In this case, Client B would have to post `{ id: 123, "value.value": null }`

Comment: Yes and client A will throw 'object reference null exception' for `"value.value"` which can be handled and further operation can be performed